# Can't install Craft CMS 3

Tags: craft3

I've downloaded craft 3 on Windows 10 using XAMP but everytime i try to install craft it skips the first step and it always put me at the second step of the install
After I fill the forms for install I get "Install failed please check logs for more info".
I also get "The info table is missing its row in C:\xampp\htdocs\crafty\vendor\craftcms\cms\src\base\ApplicationTrait.php:512"

I've checked on phpmyadmin and all the rows are empty but they are created.

Seems that running the setup from shell fixed the problem

Comment: Have you tried dropping the database and creating a new one and then running the install process again?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [yii\web\ServerErrorHttpException Craft 3 install](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/27408/yii-web-servererrorhttpexception-craft-3-install)

Comment: Also, possibly https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/25718/installing-craft-3-internal-server-error

Comment: Yes, I've tried that

Comment: So whats the actual error in the log? Which PHP Version are you using? Which MySQL Version?